# I want to select last 5 entries from DB table and display it on a page. How can I achieve it using JSP?

Tags: html, sql, jsp

I want to select last 5 entries from Database table. I have a columns ID(int), Product(string), Version(string), Description(string) in my database.

Let's say I have 50 entries in database and I need last 5 entries (i.e. 46,47,48,49 and 50) selected from table and print it on a HTML page. how can I do that using JSP?

below is my sample code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>
<%@ page language = "java" %> 
 <%   
    int id=0;
Connection connect2=null;
Statement state2=null;
ResultSet result2=null;
Connection connect=null;
Statement state=null;
ResultSet result=null;
try{Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
    connect2=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ppbu"); 
    state2 = connect2.createStatement();    
    String strQuery2 = "select MAX(ID) from kb_articles_list";  
    result2 = state2.executeQuery(strQuery2);
    while(result2.next())
    {id=result2.getInt(1);
    }
}finally {
        try {
          if (state2 != null)
            state2.close();
        }  catch (SQLException e) {}
        try {
          if (connect2 != null)
            connect2.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
      }

    out.print(id);
    for(int a=0; a<5; a++)
      {    
   try{Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");   
    connect=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ppbu");  
    state = connect.createStatement();  
    String strQuery = "select * from kb_articles_list where ID.equals(id)"; 
    result = state.executeQuery(strQuery);  
    while(result.next()){ 
            %>
            <option><%= result.getString(2)%></option>
        <% }state.close(); connect.close(); %>        
    <%    }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}    

       id--;}%>
```

Comment: A relational database table is inherently *not ordered*. You can order your result set by using the SQL `ORDER BY` clause. Simply have your client code execute the appropriate SQL for the database engine you are using. Each engine has a different method to select only 5 of the records.

Comment: Thank for prompt response. I tried "Order by" but it's not working for me. Could you give me a one line example of SQL query I can use in TRY section?

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` is the ANSI SQL way. (Unfortunately many products have their own ways here...)

Comment: It may be helpful to edit this post and add some of the code you are using. This way we can address your errors better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. I got this working using the code below.

```
String strQuery = "select * from kb_articles_list where ID="+id+"";
```